# How to compare bubble charts programmatically?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, data-visualization

1.) I have data points for a bubble chart of age vs weight [['<15 yr', 30], ['<25 yr', 60], ...]

2.) I also have 4 or 5 canned models for overweight population, malnutrition, etc.

How to tell (programmatically) if a given set of data matches any of the pre-determined models.

What specific math or statistics literature I need to look for direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In statistics this is usually studied using a [Goodness of fit test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit). Any good statistics book should cover this topic. This question might be a good candidate for [stats.stackexchange.com](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit)